# Как найти сумму элементов чётных строк матрицы? Вопрос закрыт

Tags: c#

```
namespace matrix
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        Console.WriteLine("Введите размерность матрицы MxM :");
        int M = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[,] matrix = new int[M, M];
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            for (int m = 0; m < M; m++)
            {
                matrix[j, m] = rand.Next(-10, 10);
                Console.Write(matrix[j, m] + " ");

            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            if((j + 1) % 2 == 0)

            {
                for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
                {
                    sum += matrix[j, i];
                }
            }
        }
        Console.Write(" Сумма четных строк матрицы = {0}", sum);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


}
}
```

Comment: Просто не могу понять, какая функция находит сумму чётных строк, как именно должна выглядеть эта часть кода?

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации и задайте вопрос с описанием конкретных проблем.

Answer (score 1):

```
matrix.Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 0).SelectMany(x => x).Sum();
```

естественно матрица должна выглядеть как `int[][] matrix = new int[M][];` и создание через for, new каждой строки, используйте `Linq`

Comment: Тут лабораторная работа не при чём, я пытаюсь для себя разобраться, пока что не очень получается, но за уделённое внимание     весьма благодарен

Comment: @KOD даю подсказку: [Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb397926.aspx). Там всё подробно, не надо изобретать велосипед.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно на первых парах не стоит смотреть что такое Linq и пытаться понять. Так думаю будет проще: [ccылка](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KgWStT)

```
       var sum = 0;
        // проходим по всем строкам
        for(int i = 0; i < M; i++){
            // если поппалась четная
            if(i%2 == 0){
                //cуммируем ее пройдя по всем ее элементам
                for(int j =0; j < M ; j++){

                    sum+= matrix[i,j];
                }

            }

        }

        Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Comment: Можно же просто идти с шагом два - и проверка не потребуется: `for(int i = 0; i < M; i = i + 2)`